# How to Save Information retrieved from API to MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am new to NodeJS and studying basic functionality if it.

I am working on a task to get the weather of a city from openweather.org (I use my own api key to generate). I was able to get my desired output and get the weather of a specific weather of a city specified in nodeJS.

[image]

This is the snippet of the code which comes basically from a very helpful youtube tutorial video

```
const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${address}&units=metric&appid=${process.env.API_KEY}`;

if (!address) {
    return console.log("Please enter the name of the city")
}

request(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const data = JSON.parse(body)
        //console.log(data.main.temp)
            console.log(`the weather for ${address} is ${data.main.temp}`)
       // console.log(data)
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

However, I want to save the weather, city information first to a mongodb database before showing the result or GET the  result.

Based on what I studied online, I need to create a mode schema of course of the collection wherein to POST or save the information to be retrieved from the weather website This is what I have done

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const WeatherSchema = new Schema({
    city:{
        type: String,
      
    },
    weather:{
        type: String
    }
});

const Weather = mongoose.model('weather', WeatherSchema);

module.exports = Weather;
```

What is the best way to continue this?

Comment: There's a lot more involved than can be answered here, I'd suggest following a tutorial on MongoDB first